# Request a solution for pod zero-downtime with single replia when node auto scaling

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-auto-scaling

We are encountering 502 response issues during node autoscaling using cluster autoscaler in our EKS cluster, since some pods with a single replica are out of service for a couple of minutes when pod migration from one node to another is happening.

We have observed that it is working fine when working on pod deployment. But we noticed that the pod will transition to “Terminating” status even when the pod is in “ContainerCreating” state and not a “Ready” state when the pod is running on a single replica.

We are already aware that this can be rectified by deploying multiple replicas, but we want a solution for single replica.

Looking for a solution to ensure the old pod is not terminated until a new pod is ready during node scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `maxUNavailable: 0` helps you to avoid downtime. With this Kubernetes will wait until new pod is Ready before terminating the old ones:

```
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 1
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
  type: RollingUpdate
  rollingUpdate:
  maxUnavailable: 0
  maxSurge: 100%
template:
  spec:
    terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 400
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#max-unavailable

Comment: Thanks for your response, we have tried maxUnavailable: 0. It works for pod deployment, but it doesn't work for node auto scaling.

Comment: Hm, why node upscaling triggers the change at all? You can use PodDisruptionBudget to ensure minimum available pods: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/

Comment: PDB works for multiple replica. Unfortunately, we are looking for a solution about single replica.